# Web3 not defined

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, dapps, react

I am following this tutorial here:

https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/the-ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-and-deploy-a-fully-descentralized-dapp-in-ethereum-18f0cf6d7e0e

after running `webpack` I try  to view the page but it returns a blank page.

When I check the developers console, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: web3 is not defined
>       at new App (build.js:10665)
>       at constructClassInstance (build.js:19093)
>       at updateClassComponent (build.js:20577)
>       at beginWork (build.js:20963)
>       at performUnitOfWork (build.js:22962)
>       at workLoop (build.js:23026)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (build.js:13280)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (build.js:13319)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (build.js:13176)
>       at renderRoot (build.js:23104) build.js:22485 The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in App
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
>   handling behavior. Visit https://fb.me/react-error-boundaries to learn
>   more about error boundaries. logCapturedError @ build.js:22485
>   build.js:23732 Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React
>   doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See
>   https://fb.me/react-crossorigin-error for more information.
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (build.js:13326)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (build.js:13176)
>       at renderRoot (build.js:23104)
>       at performWorkOnRoot (build.js:23752)
>       at performWork (build.js:23705)
>       at requestWork (build.js:23616)
>       at scheduleWorkImpl (build.js:23470)
>       at scheduleWork (build.js:23427)
>       at scheduleTopLevelUpdate (build.js:23931)
>       at Object.updateContainer (build.js:23969)

This is strange as my index.js (the file from which I am building from ) has

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
```

I have even tried swapping for

```
Web3 = require('web3')
```

but to no avail.

These are the references to `web3` in the js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Web3 from 'web3'
import './../css/index.css'


class App extends React.Component {

    /*
    Constructor and set the initial state of the application
    */

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lastWinner: 0,
            numberOfBets: 0,
            minimumBet: 0,
            totalBet: 0,
            maxAmountOfBets: 0,
        }

        /*
        Checking to see if Web3 variable we imported is defined or not
        */

        if(typeof web3 != 'undefined'){
            console.log("Using web3 detected from external source like Metamask")
            this.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        }else{
            this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those statements bring in `Web3` (uppercase). They won't define anything called `web3` (lowercase). I do see code in that blog post that says `web3.eth.contract(...)`. This should probably read `this.web3.eth.contract(...)` instead. But I'm not sure if that's where you're encountering the error. You might need to simplify your code down to a minimal repro and then share it.

Comment: @smarx to the rescue (`again`). Will cut out the web 3 references and post. Thank you

Comment: Reading through some more of the code, I think there are a number of `web3` references that should actually be `this.web3`. (Those things probably work fine if you have MetaMask or another injector of `web3` around, but without that, it's not going to be defined.)

Comment: I am using metamask though?

Comment: Oh, with `MetaMask` running, `web3` should really be defined globally. Is `web3` defined for you in the browser console?

Comment: I think you might be on to something. I am trying to view the `index.html` file without deploying it i.e. By opening it. Do I have to add `this` to make it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `Is web3 defined for you in the browser console?`? I use it to access dapps / deploy the contract from the tutorial and it seems to work just fine

Comment: I mean if you type `web3` into the browser console, does it say it's not defined, or does it have a value?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect that you'll need to run index.html from a web server, even if it's just a local one. (I'm personally a fan of [livereload](https://livereload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).)

Comment: when i type `web3` into my server I get `Proxy {_requestManager: s, currentProvider: MetamaskInpageProvider, eth: r, db: e.exports, shh: a, …}` will try livereload. Might just have to take a react tutorial. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "into my server"? Are you typing that into the browser console or something else? (It's whether or not it's defined in the browser that matters here.)

Comment: Sorry meant developer console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import web3 from './web3';

class App extends Component {
  state = { lastWinner: 0, numberOfBets: 0, minimumBet: 0, totalBet: 0, maxAmountOfBets: 0 };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const lastWinner = await blackjack.methods.lastWinner().call();
    const numberOfBets = await blackjack.methods.getNumberOfBets().call();

    this.setState({ lastWinner, numberOfBets });
  }
```

I would create a separate file to house all configuration code around the web3 library that would look like this:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;
```

Now, I utilized ES2016 way of initializing state where you no longer need the `constructor()` function.

You want to setup your own local instance of web3 and rip out the provider from the injected copy that is coming from Metamask and this will allow your instance of web3 to automatically connect to the Rinkeby test network and make use of all the accounts assigned to the Metamask extension.

So I created a new instance of web3 and simultaneously ripped out the injected copy of web3 provided by metamask. To rip out the provider is where you see the reference to `window` global variable.

Metamask injects web3 onto web3 global variable. The `currentProvider` has been pre configured for the Rinkeby test network.

You can then import it to the `App` file as I displayed above and then console it out to ensure it works like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import web3 from './web3';

class App extends Component {
  state = { lastWinner: 0, numberOfBets: 0, minimumBet: 0, totalBet: 0, maxAmountOfBets: 0 };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const lastWinner = await blackjack.methods.lastWinner().call();
    const numberOfBets = await blackjack.methods.getNumberOfBets().call();

    this.setState({ lastWinner, numberOfBets });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(web3.version);
  }
```