# problem connecting web3 v 1.2.1 with metamask : 'currentProvider' of undefined

Tags: web3js, contract-development, metamask, ethereumjs, web3js-v1.x

I am using **Web3 v1.2.1** with **nodejs v10** and following [this link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/). I am having issue connecting with metamask,below is my code snippet:

```
const Web3 =  require('web3')  
const window = require('window');
const web3 = new Web3(window.Web3.currentProvider);
```

The error says 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentProvider' of undefined**

I want to access the address from metamask, can someone help me with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metamask is a browser extension, so you can only use it from the browser.

You can do this in the following way:

Create a file web3-require.js:

```js
Web3=require('web3');
```

Install web3 and browserify

```js
npm install web3
npm install browserify
```

Create a browserified version of web3:

```js
browserify web3-require.js -o web3-browserify.js
```

Create test.html:

```html
Test metamask
<script src="./web3-browserify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);    
    ethereum.enable().then ( (x) => {
        alert(`Found address ${x[0]} with web3.js version ${web3.version}`); 
    } );
</script>
```

Run this from a webserver (otherwise metamask won't insert "ethereum")